# How does product count on layered navigation in Magento 2.4 is being rendered?

Tags: product, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, magento2.4, elasticsearch

i'm using magento 2.4.1 and successfully overriding the product collection for layered navigation by overriding the `getProductCollection` method. The problem is the layered navigation sidebar showing incorrect product count (the correct count is 3):

[image]
[image]

i want to try for this [solution](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Incorrect-product-count-in-layered-navigation-after-overriding/m-p/104534#M5628) however i can't find Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder in Magento 2.4.1